# How do I populate multiple records of data into a PDF form like a mail-merge?

Tags: database, adobe-acrobat, forms

I have Acrobat Pro, and I have a PDF with a form on it.  Assuming the fields in the form correspond to a data source (like rows in an RDBMS table or xml file), I want to then print multiple copies of the PDF file, with each copy having the values of a different row in the data source.

It is preferable to directly interface with an actual database, rather than having to save an XML file every time I do this.  If this involves programming that's cool too, I only posted here because the question didn't seem appropriate for StackOverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have MS Word? I've never heard of the ability to do a mail merge in acrobat but i might be wrong. Why not just do a mail merge in word? If you want the mail merge to be a pdf (for whatever reason) just send it to the pdf printer rather than your regular printer.

Comment: I already have the PDF, I was hoping I could use the form on it as described above to print